# What was Dolcetto combined with?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

Dolcetto was a human chimera, a creature synthesized by alchemically combining two or more living beings. What was the other living beings that Dolcetto was combined with?

[image: Dolcetto]

Comment: Are we talking *Brotherhood* or the 2003 anime here?

Comment: In the 2003 Anime

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague. Please add more details to the question. I am putting this on hold until you fix it, because right now no proper answer can be given.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I have edited my question.

Comment: Dolcetto states he's part dog when he is lamenting about his dog-like loyalty when he goes to aid Greed during the escape from Devil's Nest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall any of his gang having green hair. But in *Brotherhood* (and the manga), there were four gang members of Greed's:

- **Roa:** Created by being mixed with an ox or possibly a bull.
  [image: Roa]
- **Dolcetto:** Created by being mixed with a dog.
  [image: Dolcetto]
- **Martel:** Created by being mixed with a snake.
  [image: Martel]
- **Bido:** Created by being mixed with a gecko.
  [image: Bido]

Later, after Greed "changed bodies", he got two new "partners":

- **Heinkel:** Created by being mixed with a lion.
- **Darius:** Created by being mixed with some kind of ape.

Comment: Should point out that in the [comment](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/what-was-dolcetto-combined-with#comment12172_10022) the OP does clarify they are talking about the 2003 anime, as such the last 2 are from Brotherhood/Manga only as Greed doesn't changes bodies on the 2003 anime

Comment: @Memor-X that's why i asked [this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/why-fma-and-fma-brotherhood-didnt-have-different-tag)